# Vaadin 21 and Vaadin CRM Tutorial

Tags: vaadin

I have being using Vaadin CRM tutorial for Vaadin flow.  I tested to integrate with Vaadin fusion (no problem) and need to do more testing (i.e., Kotlin and VoK) before send to the development team.

When I updated my project to Vaadin 21 two things stopped working: when you select a Client in the Grid no changes are detected and also the path for the Vaadin fusion view send me and 'illegal access' from Spring Security.

I checked Vaadin portal and the Vaadin CRM tutorial for flow is now in Vaadin 21 but it is "not" the case for Vaadin flow tutorial. It is still in Vaadin 20.0.3.

I think there are some pending issued for Vaadin 21 because no tutorial exists for Vaadin flow.

Any idea whats wrong? Do I have to stay with Vaadin 20.0.3?

Comment: The tutorial is updated to Vaadin 21. The new Vaadin Security helpers block access to views by default, make sure you add `@PermitAll` (allow access to all logged-in users) to the views. See https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/tutorials/in-depth-course/login-and-authentication/#configuring-spring-security

Answer (score 3):

The new Vaadin Security helpers block access to views by default (i.e. the default is `@DenyAll`), make sure you add `@PermitAll` (allow access to all logged-in users) or alternatively `@RolesAllowed` to allow selected roles to access the views.